# Странно искажается свет в unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d, particles

В чем суть - есть некоторый скрипт c# который добавляет партиклам gameobject

Использовал этот скрипт для того чтобы заставить их светится. Но почему то свет вытянуло.

- У всех родителей размер 1,1,1
- Префаб света нормальный

```
void LateUpdate()
    { 
int count = m_ParticleSystem.GetParticles(m_Particles);

        while (m_Instances.Count < count)
            m_Instances.Add(Instantiate(m_Prefab, m_ParticleSystem.transform));

        bool worldSpace = (m_ParticleSystem.main.simulationSpace == ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.World);
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Instances.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i < count)
            {
                if (worldSpace)
                    m_Instances[i].transform.position = m_Particles[i].position;
                else
                    m_Instances[i].transform.localPosition = m_Particles[i].position;
                m_Instances[i].SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                m_Instances[i].SetActive(false);
            }
        }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: и как здесь должны помочь не идя что внутри скрипта?

Comment: мне бы хотя бы понять изо чего такое возможно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы уверены, что свет вытянуло? На скриншоте видно, что его повернуло. Возможно партиклу при создании задаётся вращении или он получает вращение другим способом.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Спасибо большое просто партикл был повернуть